# ConfigurationTenantStoreOptions in abpframework

Tags: abp

I am using abp framework. I need different connection strings based on the tenant id. Used the below code. I am getting error in ConfigurationTenantStoreOptions, I have installed package for Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration(8.0), Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy(8.0.2).
It says missing assembly reference.

```
 using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Volo.Abp.Data;
using Volo.Abp.Modularity;
using Volo.Abp.MultiTenancy;

namespace MyCompany.MyProject
{
    [DependsOn(typeof(AbpMultiTenancyModule))]
    public class MyModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceConfigurationContext context)
        {
            Configure<ConfigurationTenantStoreOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Tenants = new[]
                {
                    new TenantInformation(
                        Guid.Parse("446a5211-3d72-4339-9adc-845151f8ada0"), //Id
                        "tenant1" //Name
                    ),
                    new TenantInformation(
                        Guid.Parse("25388015-ef1c-4355-9c18-f6b6ddbaf89d"), //Id
                        "tenant2" //Name
                    )
                    {
                        //tenant2 has a seperated database
                        ConnectionStrings =
                        {
                            {ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnectionStringName, "..."}
                        }
                    }
                };
            });
        }
    }
}
```